# Ничто так ни/не к лицу

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

> В дни мира ничто так ни/не к лицу, как...

Как правильно написать?

Comment: "Не к лицу" сказуемое, я правильно понимаю? Так вот сколько я ни пытаюсь придумать, для подлежащего "ничто" приходят в голову только примеры со сказуемым с "не" (не с "ни"). Единственная встреча двух или больше НИ может быть при однородных членах, насколько я понимаю, например, *ничто никогда и нигде не сможет...*

Comment: Или я что-то напутал с терминологией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь НЕ. Это отрицание в чистом виде. ***Ничто так не к лицу*** =*Нет ничего, что было бы к лицу (так, как...)*

Поставьте в прошедшее или будущее время: ***Ничто так не было к лицу*** - снимутся последние сомнения.